# How to get data for FastReport (Delphi) from an TEdit?

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I created a report using FastReport, but the only way I know to get data to that report is from a database, I want to get data from a `TEdit` and I don't want to store anything, just writing in `TEdit` + click on the button (fastreport.preview) + print and Done.
How can I do that ? 
Please explain am new with Delphi and FastReport.

Comment: You could add the value to a memory dataset...

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `OnGetValue` event of your `TfrxReport` component as follows:

```
procedure TForm1.frxReport1GetValue(const VarName: string; var Value: Variant);
begin
  if(VarName = 'MyVariable') then
  begin
    Value := Edit1.Text;
  end;
end;
```

Then you just need to add a memo item to the report and set its value to `[MyVariable]`.

[image]

Comment: Elegant solution! Thanks, been searching for hrs.

Answer (score 3):

One possible approach is to access the `TfrxReport` and `TfrxMemoView` components at runtime. Note, that when you don't have a dataset, the `Master Data` band won't be printed, so you should use another band.

You may use the following code as a basic example. Just place one `TfrxReportTitle` band (named `'ReportTitle1'`) and one `TfrxMemoView` text object (named `'Memo1'`) on your `TfrxReport` component.

[image]

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnReportClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   memo: TfrxMemoView;
   band: TfrxReportTitle;
begin
   // Get the band
   band := (rptDemo.Report.FindObject('ReportTitle1') as TfrxReportTitle);
   // Create a memo
   memo := TfrxMemoView.Create(band);
   memo.CreateUniqueName;
   memo.ParentFont := True;
   memo.Text := edtReport.Text;
   memo.SetBounds(100, 1, 100, 16);
   memo.HAlign := haLeft;
   memo.AutoWidth := False;
   // Use existing memo
   memo := (rptDemo.Report.FindObject('Memo1') as TfrxMemoView);
   memo.Text := edtReport.Text;
   // Preview report
   rptDemo.ShowReport(False);
end;
```

Notes: This is a working example, tested with FastReport 4.7.